# Limit .getLatLng() to -90–90 and -180–180

Tags: leaflet

I have a draggable marker that's over the United States. Imagine a user drags this marker westward over the Pacific Ocean to Mount Fuji.

If I use marker.getLatLng() I would expect the coordinates to be `35.3631, 138.7306` but instead I'm getting `35.3631, -221.2694`. Is there a way to limit my latitude to between -90 and 90 and my longitude to between -180 and 180?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-wraplatlng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for Longitude, `wrap()` can be used as follows, however, Latitude will not be changed.

```
marker.getLatLng().wrap().lng
```

Reference: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#latlng-wrap